# Hide inline images by low rep users behind a spoiler button

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

In the past 8 days, we've had over [10 confirmed instances](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=+alt%3D%22enter+image+description+here%22%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&username=&why=&site=68&feedback=true+positive&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) of spam posts abusing the ability to inline images, and these are just the ones that the smoke detector caught. It might be worth considering hiding inline images behind a spoiler button for users with <10 rep.

Comment: For those who *aren't* aware, [Charcoal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) is the organisation behind the SmokeDetector community spam-detection bot.

Comment: But it's the text of the mail that positively matched spam, right? I don't think spoiler hiding image is user friendly at all!

Comment: @RadLexus All these 10 images were very very inappropiate for users to be looking at (nsfw, all of them)

Comment: Not 100% positive, but I am rather sure this is something that we can not implement on this one stack only. I think [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is therefore the better place to ask. I'd vote to migrate, but the diamond behind my name would make that final :)

Comment: @Magisch they are not all NSFW at all

Comment: @Cai The images in the confirmed spam instances are all NSFW.

Comment: @Magisch actually I just checked the metasmoke logs and not a single one from the last week was NSFW

Comment: unless you consider [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXdLV.jpg) nsfw

Comment: I consider all of these highly NSFW. Imagine you'd have your boss walking over while looking at those.

Comment: @Magisch that is nonsense

Comment: There is not 1 single image that was at all in any way NSFW in any spam (at least in the metasmoke logs) posted in the last week and saying so is very disingenuous

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkPH.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxhAN.png) nsfw?

Comment: @Cai Are we looking at the same list? How would you not class the image in [this](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/44381) as nsfw?

Comment: um... because its not? It's a normal ad. the same as i would see walking down the street on a bus stop or anywhere. It's in no way nsfw, and even if it was it is a few posts that are at that level not *all* as you said

Comment: Do you often see ads for bonerpills on the street? Because where I'm from, accessing that at work would be grounds for firing

Comment: The image itself is no more nsfw than the spam text is in the first place, but even if they are nsfw that is 3 out of 11 in the last week that are nsfw not *all*.

Comment: @Magisch if stuff like that is grounds for firing where you work, then I sincerely hope you're not browsing Stack Exchange while at work. Sheesh, I'd be fired for opening my e-mail spam folder... Thankfully, my boss isn't a chat bot that fires based on keywords. It's spam yes, but I definitely wouldn't consider that NSFW.

Answer (score 12):

I've declined this request as it's mentioned in the comments one image was questionable.  Furthermore, your request is subjected to only an eight day period and doesn't consider the entire spectrum length of this SE site and if I recall the percentage of questionable imagery is slim to none.  That said, the system, as you've pointed out, does flag accordingly for review and the community itself is fairly good about flagging so I see no validation in your request.